# Document.body in Opera

Tags: javascript, opera

I've got a problem with retrieving link to the body tag. I've tried:

1. `document.body`, unfortunately it is null
2. search body by tagName while enumerating childs of document, it's found only the head tag :(
3. `document.getElementsByTagName`, return undefined

I'm trying to get link to the body tag in onload event handler. This is a HTML code of the page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Some page</title>
        <script src="/adv.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        This is text
    </body>
</html>
```

Here the source code of `adv.js`:

```
(function () {

    var myRandom = function (min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    };

    var myFunction = function () {
        var newScriptAddr = '/adLoader.js?r=' + myRandom(1,1000000);

        var fileref = document.createElement('script');
        if (typeof fileref != "undefined")
        {
           fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
           fileref.setAttribute("src", newScriptAddr);

           document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
        }
    };

    if (window.onload)
    {
        var currOnLoad = window.onload;
        window.onload = function () {
            currOnLoad();
            myFunction();
        };
    }
    else
        window.onload = myFunction();

}) ();
```

Source code of `adLoader.js`:

```
(function () {

    var mainCnt = document.createElement('div');
    mainCnt.appendChild(document.createTextNode('The text'));

    var _body = document.body;

    if (!_body)
    {
        var htmlTag = document.documentElement;
        for(var i = 0; i < htmlTag.childNodes.length; i++)
        {
            if (htmlTag.childNodes[i].nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'body')
            {
                _body = htmlTag.childNodes[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!_body)
        _body = document.getElementsByTagName('BODY') [0];

    if (!_body)
        _body = document.getElementsByTagName('body') [0];

    if (_body)
        _body.appendChild(mainCnt);
    else
        alert('WTF!!');

}) ();
```

Browser is Opera 11.10 OS Ubuntu Linux. Is there way to get this link? My aim is to add div with `position:fixed` to the body tag.

Comment: Where is the JS? Is it inside the page (if so, why can't we see it in your sample code)? Is it in an extension? A bookmarklet? How are you attaching it to the onload handler?

Comment: Opera's own dev site has examples of `document.body.appendChild()`, so it's weird that it doesn't work. (http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/introduction-to-user-javascript/ - though this example tests for `document.body` before using it without explaining why it might not be available.)

Comment: I've added JS code, take a look please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myFunction()` doesn't return a function, so you are assigning `undefined` to `window.onload`. You probably mean `window.onload = myFunction;`

Anyway, as written at the moment, the code runs immediately and the body element hasn't been reached.

Comment: While this is the correct answer, it may puzzle you why you only hit this problem in Opera. The reason why it doesn't break in every browser is that some browsers keep parsing ahead while loading an external script that you have inserted with appendChild(), Opera doesn't so it fails with your current code. (This is a known bug we need to fix).

Comment: I just had the same issue, my `document.getElementsByTagName('BODY') [0]` Javascript line was returning a `undefined` error only in Opera. The issue was fixed by placing my Javascript code after the `</body>` tag because in Opera all external JS files load then run before continuing to the rest of the page.

Answer (score -1):

if the js code in head tag and the query the body tag before onload event, null should be got while browser just reading the head.