# Why doesn't this user script work in Opera?

Tags: javascript, opera, userscripts

This is my userscript:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           wykopSpamBlock
// @namespace      wykopSpamBlock
// @description    Skrypt ukrywający sponsorowane i polecane wykopy w serwisie wykop.pl 3.0
// @include        http://www.*wykop.pl/
// @include        http://www.*wykop.pl/strona/*
// @include        http://www.*wykop.pl/wykopalisko*
// @include        http://www.*wykop.pl/hity* 
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {

  function block(element) {

    element.style.display = 'none';
    console.log('It works');

  }

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  var Filter = new RegExp('^http://www.wykop.pl/link/partnerredirect/');
  var Entries = document.getElementById('body-con').getElementsByClassName('entry');
  var Links;

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  for (i = 0; i < Entries.length; i++) {

    Links = Entries.item(i).getElementsByTagName('div').item(0).getElementsByClassName('content').item(0).getElementsByTagName('header').item(0).getElementsByTagName('p').item(0).getElementsByTagName('a');

    if (Filter.test(Links.item(1).href) || Filter.test(Links.item(2).href)) {
      block(Entries.item(i));
    }

  }

})();
```

It works fine in Chrome and Firefox (GreaseMonkey), but it doesn't in Opera. I get this error:

```
User Javascript thread
Uncaught exception: TypeError: Cannot convert 'Entries.item(i).getElementsByTagName('div').item(0).getElementsByClassName('content').item(0)' to object
Error thrown at line 30, column 4 in <anonymous function>():
    Links = Entries.item(i).getElementsByTagName('div').item(0).getElementsByClassName('content').item(0).getElementsByTagName('header').item(0).getElementsByTagName('p').item(0).getElementsByTagName('a');
called from line 11, column 0 in program code:
    (function() {
```

And the question is, what's wrong?

//edit

For people who can't read that:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           wykopSpamBlock
// @namespace      wykopSpamBlock
// @description    Skrypt ukrywający sponsorowane i polecane wykopy w serwisie wykop.pl 3.0
// @include        http://www.*wykop.pl/
// @include        http://www.*wykop.pl/strona/*
// @include        http://www.*wykop.pl/wykopalisko*
// @include        http://www.*wykop.pl/hity* 
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {

  function block(element) {

    element.style.display = 'none';
    console.log('It works');

  }

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  var Filter = new RegExp('^http://www.wykop.pl/link/partnerredirect/');
  var Entries = document.getElementById('body-con').getElementsByClassName('entry');

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  for (i = 0; i < Entries.length; i++) {

    var EntriesItem = Entries.item(i);
    var Div = EntriesItem.getElementsByTagName('div');
    var DivItem = Div.item(0);
    var Content = DivItem.getElementsByClassName('content');
    var ContentItem = Content.item(0);
    var Header = ContentItem.getElementsByTagName('header');
    var HeaderItem = Header.item(0);
    var Paragraph = HeaderItem.getElementsByTagName('p');
    var ParagraphItem = Paragraph.item(0);
    var Links = ParagraphItem.getElementsByTagName('a');

    if (Filter.test(Links.item(1).href) || Filter.test(Links.item(2).href)) {
      block(Entries.item(i));
    }

  }

})();
```

and error:

```
[26.09.2011 20:35:07] JavaScript - http://www.wykop.pl/
User Javascript thread
Uncaught exception: TypeError: Cannot convert 'ContentItem' to object
Error thrown at line 35, column 4 in <anonymous function>():
    var Header = ContentItem.getElementsByTagName('header');
called from line 11, column 0 in program code:
    (function() {
```

//edit 2

Here is full html of entry. Content starts in 21 line.

```
<article class="entry brbotte8 pding15_0  {id:891309}">
  <div class="clr rel">

    <div class="fleft diggbox">
      <a href="http://www.wykop.pl/link/dig/%7E2/891309/55a55552de3fac6ececb6a8933938e71-1317062985/log_ref_0,index,log_ref_m_0,index,log_ref_n_0," class="block tcenter tdnone diggit ">
        <span class="icon inlblk diggcount cff5917 large fbold vtop animated ">
          22
        </span>
        <span class="block action small br3 bre3">
          wykop
        </span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <a href="http://www.wykop.pl/ramka/891309/policjant-strzelil-nastolatkowi-w-twarz-taserem-wideo/" class="image  rel fright">
      <div class="lazy">
        <!--<img src="http://c0692282.3.cdn.imgwykop.pl/hi_34VehOZEwdnDXdwlMEBOWbkmNGIzrPM0.jpg" alt="Policjant strzelił nastolatkowi w twarz taserem [wideo" class="fright border marginleft15" width="104" height="74" />-->
      </div>
    </a>

    <div class="content">

      <header>
        <h2 class="xx-large lheight20">
          <a href="http://www.wykop.pl/ramka/891309/policjant-strzelil-nastolatkowi-w-twarz-taserem-wideo/"  class="link">
            <span class="fbold">Policjant strzelił nastolatkowi w twarz taserem [wideo</span>
          </a>
        </h2>
        <p class="small cc6">
          <a href="http://www.wykop.pl/reklama/" class="link gray" title="Przejdź do Reklama Wykop.pl">
            <span>
              Wykop Poleca
            </span>
          </a> 
          dodany 
          <time title="2011-09-26 19:37:24" datetime="2011-09-26T19:37:24+02:00" pubdate>
            1 godz. temu
          </time> 
          przez 
          <a href="http://www.wykop.pl/ludzie/Saper86/" class="link gray color color-1">
            <span>
              Saper86
            </span>
          </a>
           z 
          <a href="http://www.wykop.pl/link/partnerredirect/891309/policjant-strzelil-nastolatkowi-w-twarz-taserem-wideo/" rel="nofollow" class="link gray" title="Przejdź do Policjant strzelił nastolatkowi w twarz taserem [wideo">
            <span>
              gadzetomania.pl
            </span>
          </a>                                      
          do 
          <a href="http://ciekawostki.wykop.pl/" title="Ciekawostki" class="link gray" rel="nofollow">
            <span>
              Ciekawostki
            </span>
          </a>
          <a href="http://www.wykop.pl/link/891309/policjant-strzelil-nastolatkowi-w-twarz-taserem-wideo/" class="marginleft10 caf small tdnone">
            <span class="icon inlblk comments mini vtop margintop5 ">&nbsp;</span> 
            <span class="hvline  link gray">13 komentarzy</span>
          </a>
        </p>
      </header>

      <p class="lheight18">
        <a href="http://www.wykop.pl/link/891309/policjant-strzelil-nastolatkowi-w-twarz-taserem-wideo/" class="block ce1">
          <span class="c22">Oceńcie sami czy postąpił właściwie</span>
        </a>
      </p>

    </div>

  </div>

</article>
```

Comment: I'd try throwing alerts in wherever possible, to see where they are triggered (and therefore what line is causing the problem). Opera is a strange animal.

Comment: http://wykop.pl - it runs with this page (as user script). Full list of links is in comment, lines 4-7.

Comment: This is an interesting problem - if it is a bug, I'd like to understand what's wrong. :) Make sure the user JS file is named something.user.js to make it run in Greasemonkey-compatible mode (i.e. before the load event). You could also try to run the code from the DOMContentLoaded event. Helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest breaking each piece of this long line into individual steps and find out which of the 8 steps is failing and that should give you a clue:

```
Links = Entries.item(i).getElementsByTagName('div').item(0).getElementsByClassName('content').item(0).getElementsByTagName('header').item(0).getElementsByTagName('p').item(0).getElementsByTagName('a');
```

I really have no idea what's causing the problem.  It works for both of us in jsFiddle, just not in the greasemonkey environment.  Do you have any other greasemonkey scripts that are modifying the page and changing the DOM on you?

Other than that, the only other thing I can think of is to switch to using document.querySelectorAll() when it's present.   Since that is supported in recent versions of Opera, that may avoid whatever issues your code is having.  You can see a sample implementation in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/5hJLn/.  This selector doesn't generate exactly the same result as your code with any HTML, but I think it works for the HTML you have.  You can consider tweaking the selector if you want.  This selector is a little less brittle because it doesn't rely on the exact position of various tags as much as your code.

The general idea (implemented in that jsFiddle) is like this:

```
if (document.querySelectorAll) {
    var Links = document.querySelectorAll("#body-con .content header p a");
    // turn the links we found green just to show that the code executed properly
    for (var j = 0; j < Links.length; j++) {
        Links[j].className = "target2";
    }
} else {

    var Entries = document.getElementById('body-con').getElementsByClassName('entry');


    for (var i = 0; i < Entries.length; i++) {

        var EntriesItem = Entries.item(i);
        var Div = EntriesItem.getElementsByTagName('div');
        var DivItem = Div.item(0);
        var Content = DivItem.getElementsByClassName('content');
        var ContentItem = Content.item(0);
        var Header = ContentItem.getElementsByTagName('header');
        var HeaderItem = Header.item(0);
        var Paragraph = HeaderItem.getElementsByTagName('p');
        var ParagraphItem = Paragraph.item(0);
        var Links = ParagraphItem.getElementsByTagName('a');

        // turn the links we found red just to show that the code executed properly
        for (var j = 0; j < Links.length; j++) {
            Links[j].className = "target";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote?  The error says it's on this line and you need to know which of the 8 steps in this line is causing the problem, right?  There's no HTML to look at and no way to reproduce the problem so there's not much else we could suggest.  By my understanding of the question, this is the most we can answer given the info we have.

Comment: It is clearly Entries.item(i).getElementsByTagName('div').item(0).getElementsByClassName('content').item(0). Read the second line of logs.

Comment: @ciembor - Yeah, so they have to figure out which step in that is causing the problem, right?  And then compare that to the HTML and figure out why it might be failing?

Comment: Man... the last one. It's obvious where it is. The question is why it occurs.

Comment: @ciembor - maybe the error message was crystal clear to you, but it wasn't to me so my first step would have been to isolate exactly which item was causing the problem and see exactly what it was returning.  Then, compare to the HTML (which the OP has not provided) and come up with a theory for why.  If you know more than that, please provide an answer yourself.  I'm happy to step aside - just trying to help and explain how I would debug this.

Comment: Yeah, it's clear that ContentItem is likely null, but we'd have to see the HTML to offer ideas on why that happens.

Comment: ContentItem is undefined. Html above. I tried also with [0] instead of item(0).

Comment: One observation which probably doesn't have anything to do with the problem is that `{id:891309}` is not a valid class name in your `<article>` tag.  Legal class names must begin an underscore, dash or letter.

Comment: This jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/2eUGZ/ works fine in Opera 10.51.  Must be something different about your actual page vs. the code you posted that I used in the jsFiddle.

Comment: The only other idea I have is to use document.querySelectorAll() when it's present.  See code example add to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works. I'm still curious why the previous one doesn't - but it really works! Thanks a lot for your time, and I'm sorry for my emotions...

Comment: I reached this post after having the same issue in Opera and found my answer in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516547/document-body-in-opera)

Answer (score 0):

I used `getElementsByTagName('div').item(1)` instead of `getElementsByClassName('content').item(0)`. It works. I think there must be a bug in Opera's implemetation of getElementsByClassName.

//edit

Ehh... now I get the same error for `getElementsByTagName('header').item(0).`.

Comment: A jsFiddle of your original code here with the HTML you posted above http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/2eUGZ/ works for me in Opera 11.51.  Something is different about your actual page from what you posted.

Comment: Yes, it works. Even more. it works even with copy/paste source code of main page: http://jsfiddle.net/2eUGZ/3/ .

Comment: And even with my first spaghetti: http://jsfiddle.net/2eUGZ/5/ . That's strange O_o.

Comment: I really don't get it. It doesn't works as userscript. I think it's time to say "sorry, goodbye" to Opera's users.

Answer (score -2):

Change the way you implement it. Try another approaching to anonymous function and use Opera dragonfly to test it.